# Calling a function inside .a file in Xamarin

Tags: android, c++, qt, xamarin, mingw

I have a requirement to use C++ code developed using QT inside Xamarin.

The process is like (all done on Windows):
1. Configure and create a static library in QT 5.2
2. Add an Android build kit (MinGW 32) and build the static library for armeabi
3. Use the static library to do P/Invoke inside C# in Xamarin

The problem is that Step 2 above produces a .a file. This is a Linux native object file and I am very sure it will run in Android. How do I use it to perform DllImport and do a P/Invoke? Pardon my ignorence here, I have tried to rename the file to .so and it didn't really help.

Let me know if you need any clarification, your suggestion is very much appreciated.

Thanks, 
Manoj

Comment: `.o` is an object file, linux has nothing to do with these. You have to link all your object files to get an executable

Comment: .o is not the same as .so. Renaming is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

You are building a static library. These are meant to be included and loaded at compile time for the programs that use them. What you want it to build a library that can be loaded dynamically, which should end in .so (no you can't just rename it).

You likely need a dynamic library in QT too.